# Can listen_addresses really be set to a list?

Tags: postgresql

I have a VM with IP address 192.168.0.192 running postgreSQL.

If I specify

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then I can connect from another VM at 192.168.0.191 and from localhost.

But I can't seem to **use a list to tell** postgreSQL to use those two addresses.  If I change listen_addresses to a list:

```
listen_addresses = '192.168.0.191, localhost'
```

then I can no longer connect from 192.168.0.191.

I notice that almost all examples on stackexchange set listen_addresses to '*'.  Is this because the list form does not work?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, `listen_addresses` can be set to a list of addresses *on the local host* to bind to for listening.

In your example:

> listen_addresses = '192.168.0.191, localhost'

If the local machine has IP `192.168.0.192`, you should specify that IP, not the remote host `192.168.0.191` IP. PostgreSQL cannot bind to the IP address of a remote host.

You're not saying "who is allowed to connect", you're saying "which interfaces should PostgreSQL accept connections on". The "who's allowed to connect" bit is next, and is configured in `pg_hba.conf`.

So: Try `'192.168.0.192, localhost'`. Or just `*`, since you probably actually want to listen on all network interfaces.

Comment: It works.  So is there any practical difference between the list and '*'?

Comment: @zabouti Sure. If your server has (say) two external network interfaces, you can tell PostgreSQL to only bind on one of them, so it's not even possible to make a TCP connection to Pg on the other. It's mostly an extra level of security for a system that has multiple interfaces to different security domains. Quite handy in combination with VLANs, virtual switches, etc. The most common use is setting it to `localhost` so that TCP/IP connections are not possible from any external network interface, only the loopback address.

Comment: @CraigRinger: a very good answer!

Comment: @CraigRinger you should add those comments to your answer. That's very useful information.

Comment: Yeah I think the comment might be even better than the answer. Rock on Craig!

Comment: Also, you need to restart postgresql after changing listen_addresses.

Comment: hmm, why this not works to me, when I add some another host or IP ?  only * works for me. Postgre12

Answer (score 6):

I've found that instead of using `localhost` it needs to be `127.0.0.1` if you're specifying any other addresses as well.

So in my case of listening on the Docker host IP address as well as localhost, but not the external IP, this doesn't work (I get a connection refused from inside my Docker containers):

```
listen_addresses = '172.17.0.1, localhost'
```

But this does:

```
listen_addresses = '172.17.0.1, 127.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

The entry 0.0.0.0 allows listening for all IPv4 addresses and :: allows listening for all IPv6 addresses. If the list is empty, the server does not listen on any IP interface at all, in which case only Unix-domain sockets can be used to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

For security reason we need to add IP addresses that will be bound to the socket.

For example, when we use `'localhost'` we will bind two addresses `127.0.0.1` and `::1` both are the loopback addresses for IPv4 and IPv6, respectively. Therefore, the `postgresql` service will be available in the localhost.

#### But, Teo if I want to connect to this service remotely from the same network or from an external network?

In that case, we need to add our `ip` that has access to those networks. Usually the IP of our main interface. For example, if your interface `enp2s0` has the `inet` `192.168.0.20` then we can configure the `postgresql.conf` like this:

```sh
listen_addresses = '192.168.0.20, 127.0.0.1'
```

This configuration will support IPv4, if you also need to support IPv6, then add the `inet6` of your main interface.

So, to summarize, `listen_addresses` controls which interfaces accept connection attempts. This help prevent repeated malicious connection requests on insecure network interfaces.